# How to fix 414(Request-URI Too Long) error in android Asynctask?

Tags: android, sql-server, wcf-rest

Using wcf rest service I am posting data into SQL server from my android application using asynctask httpget, but it was throwing `414 error`.The maximum URL length is 2097151 but my URL length is 20097.
Here is the code that's throwing error:

```
String url="http://192.168.1.6:44123/MobileServices.svc/GetAllReportsMethod?";
        //String url="http://192.168.1.200:51123/MobileServices.svc/GetAllReportsMethod?";
        //String url="http://192.168.1.21:55123/MobileServices.svc/GetAllReportsMethod?";
        String parameters="spName="+URLEncoder.encode(spname)+"&inputxele="+URLEncoder.encode(inputxele)+"&transType="+URLEncoder.encode(transtype);
        InputStream instream =null;
        String ur=url+parameters;
        String count=String.valueOf(ur.length());
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get=null;
            try
            {
                get=new HttpGet(ur);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpResponse response=null;
            try
            {
                response = httpclient.execute(get);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String msg="";
            String line = ""; 
            while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                msg += line;
            }
            Log.i("msg=",""+msg);
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                result="success";
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you sure that it's a client-side problem? Have you tried using this URL in the browser, for example?

Comment: Yeah i had tried it its working,but whenever i tried to send large data its throwing the above error.Is there any thing to change in the web config file

Comment: then it isn't related to android.